# Visual Studio 2015 Extensions - What is the equivalent to Eclipse Plugin Perspective

Tags: visual-studio-2015, eclipse-plugin, perspective

In Visual Studio 2015 Extensions, what is the equivalent of a perspective in Visual Studio?

In Eclipse I can have a Plugin that opens as a new perspective.

However, in VS Extensions, I can only find examples that open up a new WPF window, as opposed to being integrated into the IDE.

Can someone with Eclipse Plugin and VS Extensions experience point me in the right direction.

Comment: There is no such thing really... Closest thing is probably the Window -> Save/Apply Window Layout.

Comment: @jessehouwing Even programmatically?

Comment: The concept doesn't exist. Sorry.